# {"detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."} postman and DRF

Tags: authentication, django-rest-framework, postman, authorization

views.py

```
class ProductViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
   authentication_classes = [TokenAuthentication] 
   permission_classes = [IsAdminUser]
   queryset = ProductInfo.objects.all().order_by('-id')
   serializer_class = ProductSerializer
   filter_backends = (filters.SearchFilter,)
   search_fields = ['title','code','owner__username']
```

setting.py

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
),
'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
)
```

this is my view.. I tried several times to use my token to authenticate my user,, then use IsAdmin User permission to have an access to my view. you know. modelviewset supports POST,GET,PUT,DELETE method.I can't send request with none of them. my main issue is postman... I give my token to postman and I expect to authenticate my user via it's token. but now it looks like I have a big issue with authentication and permission and maybe with postman.

it drives me crazy....
[image]

[image]

please help me. I'm new to postman... I don't know really about it. I just know it made me crazy.

Comment: Did you tried capitalize the T letter? "Token" instead "token". Ref: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication

Comment: First on postman value field, you must use only the actual value of your token.
Second, maybe is not the source of your problem but could works is changing:
From 'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated' -> 'rest_framework.permissions.DjangoObjectPermissions'
Or even change your Default Authentication Classes.